# Linux find files with string and print last access time

Tags: linux, find, grep

I have a command which finds all the files containing a certain string on linux:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep 'string' -sl
```

What I want is to also print the time and date that the file was last modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
grep -rl "string" *|xargs ls -l
```

If you want only the times:

```
grep -rl "string" *|xargs ls -l|awk '{print $NF, $6, $7 }'
```

will print something like:

```
file1 2012-03-25 12:44
file2 2012-03-26 00:30
```